# Draw a 3D surface terminating smoothly on a plane

Tags: pgfplots

The following code works like gangbusters but for one thing: it cuts off instead of smoothly reaching the ellipse, x^2/4+y^2/9=1.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            unit vector ratio={1 1 1},
            axis lines=middle,
            xmin=-2.25, xmax=2.25,
            ymin=-3.25, ymax=3.25,
            zmin=-0.25, zmax={2*sqrt(3)+0.5},
            xlabel=\(x\),
            ylabel=\(y\),
            zlabel=\(z\),
            ytick={-3,0,3},
            ztick={0,{2*sqrt(3)}},
            zticklabels={\(0\),\(2\sqrt3\)}
        ]
            \addplot3[surf,samples=41,restrict expr to domain={x^2/4+y^2/9}{0:1}]{0};
            \addplot3[surf,samples=41,restrict expr to domain={x^2/4+y^2/9}{0:1}]{2*sqrt(3-y^2/3)-2*abs(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have searched everywhere to find how to deal with this.  I have tried using an `ifthenelse` function returning `nan` when the function falls outside the given ellipse.  I have tried a `max` function with the given formula as one option or `-0.3` (outside the `zmin`) as the other.  The first produced the same output that I have.  The second was better and worse.  It takes the surface to the ellipse, but then it adds a plane around it, which I don't want.  I really just want to see the given surface touch the ellipse all the way around in a smooth curve.

I suspect that increasing the sampling will improve the result, but in 3d plots, that can only go so far, before the compiler fails.

Comment: What is your minimal working example? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: I've added the missing code for an MWE.  I frequently forget that part here.